# Dataframe write rows in column next to each other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe in the following format:

```
index      id           employee    date            week      result
1          1234565      Max         2022-07-04      27        Project 1
2          1234565      Max         2022-07-04      27        Task 1
3          1234565      Max         2022-07-04      27        Full-Time
4          1256391      Susanne     2022-07-05      27        Project 2                         
5          1256391      Susanne     2022-07-05      27        Task 2
6          1256391      Susanne     2022-07-05      27        Full-Time
```

What I want to achieve is the following format:

```
index      id           employee    date            week      result        task       status
1          1234565      Max         2022-07-04      27        Project 1     Task 1     Full-Time
2          1256391      Susanne     2022-07-05      27        Project 2     Task 2     Full-Time
```

So the logic is, that always 3 rows belong together. Is there any way to achieve the desired outcome? Besides the Index column, there is not a unique index.

Comment: create helper columns `df['new'] = df.index // 3 + 1` and then use `pivot`

Comment: I've tried it, but it brings not the desired outcome. I have created a helping column with worked well, but creating the Pivot was not working as expected. Am I missing something?

df.pivot(index=['id','employee','date','week','new'], columns='result', values='result')

Comment: what is your pivot code?

Comment: df.pivot(index=['id','employee','date','week','new'], columns='result', values='result')

Comment: change columns='new'

Comment: Then I get an error: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. If I add the 'index' column to the pivot index, it is writing all the entries from "new" next to each other, so the table gets very big